# Finding the road with Google map api

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

Im working on a Android project which should trigger a method when i come near a road from a building or something
is there a way to detect near by road in android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Google Maps Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/intro#overview), more specifically use the snap to roads feature which [snaps the points](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/advanced#processing_long_paths) (lat/lng) to their most likely position on roads using the Roads API.

Comment: if you can help me to find a good sample or a place where i can find i would be more grateful because i have been searching for a about a week in google now because im new to android

Comment: How about this sample: https://github.com/googlemaps/roads-api-samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/maps/roadsapi/MainActivity.java - check the code for `mTaskSnapToRoads AsyncTask`

Comment: Pleasure, let me know if it helped!

Comment: thing is its giving a route its like finding directions i dont need that what i need is  I WANT TO KNOW AM I IN A ROAD OR NOT !!!

Comment: Try reverse geocoding. Reverse geocoding is the process of transforming a (latitude, longitude) coordinate into a (partial) address. So was thinking if you supply a latitude and longitude to the geocoder and it doesn't return an address then we are not on a road and if it does return a full address we are on a road. Try this `Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault()); List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude,1);`

Comment: thanks clieve Seebregts we used a very similar aproach to that by filtering the nearby places with the type "route"